# Wrong popup displaying when click on the icon in the "Subscribe to RSS"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

In the bottom of the [Jobs page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), there is an option to **Subscribe to RSS**. When clicking on the link it opens the popup to provide the URL for the RSS.

But if you are press on the icon (circled in the screenshot), it will open the same page as the popup instead of the RSS URL popup.

[image: SO JOBS RSS]

Inspect the element, the `<a href="/jobs/feed"` is applied only for the **Subscribe to RSS** text only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! I've fixed it and it will make it to production on the next build.

Comment: This bug can be reproducible now. In the `rev 2017.12.7.28085` it exist.

Comment: Still the bug is exists. `rev 2019.8.23.34694`